# Topology on the real numbers such that all polynomials are continuous but cosine is not continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

So the question asks to find a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ so that all the polynomials are continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ but $\cos(x)$ is not continuous as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I looked at another similar question in stack exchange: [A Topology such that the continuous functions are exactly the polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427634/a-topology-such-that-the-continuous-functions-are-exactly-the-polynomials)
I think this is a special case of my question since it requires all other functions to not be continuous.

Other than that I thought maybe the solution could be based on how cosine is a periodic function unlike the polynomials, so maybe I should take out some infinite sets from the topology but that still wouldn't be enough since the topology would be closed under unions. So I am not even sure if there exists such topology.

Comment: How about the cofinite topology?

Comment: Could you please explain how the in the cofinite topology the cosine function would not be continuous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's put the cofinite topology on the real line, and suppose that the cosine function is continuous. Than the counterimage of $0$ should be closed; but it has infinitely many points, and in the cofinite topology a subset is closed iff it is finite.